# How can I create a side menu to the left of my main content?

Tags: css

I'm working on a website and I have everything wrapped inside this block of code which sets everything nicely in the middle of the web page and has a width of 780px. I do plan on making it more responsive down the line but for now this is exactly how I want my website to look on large monitors. Because of the width there's enough room for a small menu that I can place to the very left of the main content. I want this menu to include things like the users first name, job position and other basic information. An example would be how LinkedIn's page looks after you log in. When I tried including the code it set itself on top of my main content instead of to the left.

```css
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 780px;
}

.sidenav {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main class="content">
  <div class="sidenav">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="main__home">
    <form action="" method="POST">
      ...
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

**What I've tried**

I have tried using `flex` and setting the `justified-content` and `align-items` both to `left` but that just stretched the width across the screen. I've also tried setting the `float` to `left` but that also ruined the width and made everything small. I've also moved the `sidenav` code outside of the `content` block but all that did was stretch the width to the entire screen.

Comment: This is a good time to use Grd. Check out some of the options offered here: https://gridbyexample.com/patterns/

Answer (score 2):

You can add `display: flex;` to `.content` to make them sid by side.
To fix the sizing issues you can set the `.sidenav` width with `flex-basis: 150px;`(or maybe another value) then add `flex-grow: 1;` to `.main__home` and it will fill the rest of the width.
Full css below:

```
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 780px;
  display: flex;
}

.sidenav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

.main__home {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is hang a menu on the left of your main content then use `position: relative` on your container to create a new [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) then `position: absolute` on the side bar. Use `right: 100%` to push it all the way to the left of your block (it sounds counter-intuitive but it pushes the left hand edge of the sidenav all the way beyond the container).

For screen sizes below your total width, use a media query to change how it displays.

```css
.content {
  position: relative; /* define a new containing block */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 780px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.main__home {
  background: lightgray;
}

.sidenav {
  position: absolute; /* added this */
  right: 100%; /* push the right hand edge all the way to the left edge of the container */
  
  /* this is all just prettification */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<main class="content">
  <div class="sidenav">
     <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="main__home">
    <form action="" method="POST">
      main
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: thank you. this is exactly what I was looking for. is it still okay to use `right` when building a responsive website?

Comment: It is but remember using position: absolute takes the sidebar outside the normal flow so the height and width have to be defined by you (or the content). changing the screen width or height won't affect it hugely.  It's useful for little side widgets or menus. If you've got a lot of content to put in it, you'll probably be better of using flex or grid.